# How Make Form Input With Auto Tag HTML

Tags: php, html, forms

[image]

How to make form input like above? is it plugin? how to add to my own website?
i want every user make enter, the component auto add tag < br >

Comment: question is unclear but i think you want to create editors on your page.check jQuery editors plugin for this purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like TinyMCE

https://www.tinymce.com/
Docs : https://www.tinymce.com/docs/

**Demo :** https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/basic-example/

Your  will be replace by a TinyMCE box.

Answer (score 0):

Use these two scripts:

You can also used input as the replacement of textarea

```html
<html>
<head>
     <script src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js"></script>
     <script>tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea' });</script>
</head>
<body>
     <form>
     <textarea>Next, get a free TinyMCE Cloud API key!</textarea>
     </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use following plugins.

1. [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)
2. [TinyMCE](https://www.tinymce.com/)
3. [HtmlEditor](http://www.procato.com/htmleditor/)